# Finding login page of website programmatically

Tags: java, api

I was trying to sign up with a whoIs api provider to get the login page for a certain website, but it doesn't seem like they provide that kind of information, is there a better way to figure that out?

I tried these sites:

```
https://jsonwhois.com/
http://domainr.build/
```

But it doesn't seem like the json they return contains the login page

For example, if I enter

```
google.com
```

I want a response that contains

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin#identifier
```

If I enter

```
yahoo.com
```

I want a response of

```
https://login.yahoo.com
```

Comment: Who says a website must have a separate login page?  Who says a website must have login functionality at all?  There are standards for various kinds of authentication technologies, but no standards whatever for web-based authentication UIs.

Comment: Right, but if there's no login page, then I just want to get a null value. If there is, I want to go there.

I was hoping since there are a lot of whois technologies that include info about a site, login info might be one of those

Comment: Whois itself -- and therefore anything built on top of it -- contains no such information.  Whois contains information about *domain registrations*, not about any services or web sites running at those domains, with the exception of domain-name services.  I've no knowledge of any public database containing the kind of information you're after.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply because the redirection happens after. It depends wether you're looking after a redirection by a 301 response or a 401.

Comment: Maybe my question is too vague, essentially all I want to do is tell the users the login page for the website they type in, so I don't do any authentication at all, I just give them the login url. So it's literally just a string